longitudinal regression but cohort is different in each year?
In most textbook examples for longitudinal regression, they describe situations where there is a group of people that is followed up over a period of time and measured. Sometimes people drop out of the study (e.g. censoring) and sometimes people enter the study later ... but in general, the bulk of the group stays similar.
My question is about the following: If some researchers want to find out if removing junk food in the university cafeteria resulted in healthier students. The researchers took a random group of students (each year 100 males and 100 females), asked them if they eat junk food in general and recorded some fitness indicators (e.g. time for 100 yard dash, number of situps). The researchers do this 4 years before the junk food was removes and 4 years after the junk food was removed.  Research questions would be like:  since the removal of junk food, male student's fitness improved but female student's fitness remained stable
As an extreme example, lets assume that the same student never appears more than once in the whole study. In this extreme example, can longitudinal regression still be used here (ex: marginal model)...or do we at least need some of the same students to be measured more than once?
PS: Assume the researchers try to ensure that the students each year have similar properties as students from previous years

What you describe just sounds like a cross-sectional design over a time period. A similar approach would be something like an independent samples-same cohort design, or simply a quasi-longitudinal design, where the same cohort is followed over time but different people are used from that same cohort each time.
The reason why this is a potentially interesting is because the differences in effects in the case you describe may be completely based on the cohort (one group happens to be smarter than the other, etc.) or other related confounding. However, longitudinal research isn't always the smoking gun one expects in these situations (a really good paper on this can be found here). As an example, it is well known that longitudinal data is prone to practice effects (see here for an example of how time really influences that part). I offer an interesting study on the subject in the ageing psychology research as one example of how these three approaches can sometimes have wildly different conclusions.
In this study, they used longitudinal, cross-sectional, and quasi-longitudinal observations to check z-score changes of a variable over the lifespan of around 5,000 subjects (the below plot is based on memory change of those participants).

Notice a strange trend. The cross-sectional and longitudinal data all form a similar trend. But at many points the longitudinal data has almost opposite relations from the other two trend lines. There are many potential reasons for this, but if we go back to our issue of practice effects, it should come as no surprise that some subjects may have simply performed better the next two periods simply from knowing what was on the test already. The purely cross-sectional observations and quasi-longitudinal observations instead yield fairly consistent negative associations with age (a variable measuring "speed" in this study seemed less prone to this issue, so it wasn't universal).
We can only speculate to some degree whether we should treat one method better over the other, or why they turned out that way in the first place, but it makes for an interesting case for considering your data and assumptions about that data before picking one of these methods. But this gets further muddied by the fact that you are also making inference about an intervention effect applied to this kind of data. Is the intervention causing people to become healthier because of the intervention itself, or is it simply because you replaced one group of unhealthy people with another that is already healthy? These are important considerations that add to the complexity of the problem. However, you have considered something like matching to reduce individual differences, so techniques like these can take at least some of the guesswork out.
